# Modify all object inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Array of objects like this :

```
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": "minivan",
    "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
    "capacity": 7
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": "station wagon",
    "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
    "capacity": 5
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to make a change on all objects and return this array without unnecessary information ( I don't need to get the type and registration ) and have my array of objects like this:

```
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "capacity": 7
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "capacity": 5
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Hint. Use map function.

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried. Even if you feel it is extremely wrong.

Comment: `cars.map(({color,capacity}) => ({color, capacity}))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach`:

```js
    cars.forEach(car => {
     delete car.registration
     delete car.type
    })
```

Alternatively, if you want to create a new array, you can use the `map` function:

```js
   const newCars = cars.map(car => {
     return { color: car.color, capacity: car.capacity }
    })
```

Comment: I tried to run the second one it's always returning Undefined

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad! I used forEach again instead of map. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer. You can use it for typescript too.

```js
let cars = [
    {
        "color": "purple",
        "type": "minivan",
        "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
        "capacity": 7
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "type": "station wagon",
        "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
        "capacity": 5
    },
]

let newCars = cars.map(function (car)  {
    return {"color" : car.color, "type": car.type};
});

console.log(newCars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each item in the array, and remove what you don't need. But that's just Javascript. For Typescript, if you want to update the type of the array as well, you may use casting:

```
const newCars = cars.map(car => {
  delete car.registration;
  delete car.type;
  return car;
}) as {color: string; capacity: number}[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash`

```
_.map(cars, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['color','capacity']));
```